# ALTER TO - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

no meu Banco tenho 2 stored procedures ,dbo.A e dbo.B .
na procedure dbo.A existem os parametros @nome , @rua
na procedure dbo.B existem os parametros @cep , @telefone

porem preciso também ter o parametro @rua do dbo.A , no dbo.B .
Preciso fazer via QuerySql do Microsoft SQL SERVER Management.

Comment: Poderia [edit] sua pergunta e esclarecer o problema específico ou acrescente outros detalhes para destacar exatamente o que precisa, como parte do código. Consulte a página [ask] para obter ajuda no esclarecimento desta pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se entendi direito a sua pergunta.
Para adicionar um parametro a uma procedure, você precisa reescrever ela por inteiro. Não tem como dar alter apenas dos parametros.

Por exemplo:
digitando sp_helptext dbo.B
você vai ter algo do tipo:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.B
  @cep varchar(20)
, @telefone varchar(20)
AS
SELECT @cep, @telefone
```

Para adicionar um parametro novo nela, você teria que fazer:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.B 
  @cep varchar(20)
, @telefone varchar(20)
, @rua varchar(200)
AS
SELECT @cep, @telefone, @rua
```